# Getting error in controller while unit testing using karma jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm getting this error while I'm running unit test using Karma-Jasmine

> ReferenceError: myModule is not defined

My sample test case is as follows..

> describe("Unit Testing", function() {

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule.common'));
var scope, ngTableParams, filter ,testTableParam;

it('should have a commonController controller', function () {
    expect(myModule .common.controller('commonController ', function (commonController ) {
            $scope:scope;
            ngTableParams:ngTableParams;
            $filter: filter;
            tableParams: testTableParam
        }
    )).toBeDefined();
});});
```

I have injected the module name as myModule.common.
Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Is the space between `myModule` and `.common` in your code?  Or only the example you posted?

Comment: Is the file that declares your module in the `karma.conf.js`?

Comment: Sorry.There is no space between myModule and common.I have included the file that declares my module

Comment: I think you should try to change your test like this http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/dc1bymzm/1/. The error "myModule" is not defined occurs on this line "expect(myModule.common.controller( ..." and actually there is no "myModule.common" object inside your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code snippet it might help

```
describe('testing myModule.common', function() {
    var $rootScope, $scope, $filter, $controller, ngTableParams, testTableParam;
    beforeEach(module('myModule.common'));
    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function($injector) {
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $filter = $injector.get('$filter');
            testTableParam = $injector.get('testTableParam');
            ngTableParams = $injector.get('ngTableParams');
            $controller = $injector.get('$controller')('commonController ', {
                $scope: $scope
            });

        });
    });
    it('testing commonController ', function() {
        expect('commonController ').toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

It will solve your problem